# How can a TMP file be executable and run?

Tags: windows-7

A program was installing on a computer, the window wouldn't close, I opened process explorer and dragged process explorer's 'shield' over the window to see what exe it was, and it said it was

[image]

I looked in task manager and I see it there too

[image]

It is a file with extension tmp

how is it executing?

gnuwin32's *nix style  file commmand shows it is an executable file (with tmp extension)

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp>file set4C29.tmp<ENTER>
set4C29.tmp; PE32 executable for MS Windows (GUI) Intel 80386 32-bit

C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp>
```

I am still curious though how a file with .tmp extension could be in task manager.

I wouldn't mind knowing what file executed it, though I can't tell

Process explorer shows some info about it. I know it's not malicious. But I have never seen a tmp file in task manager, i'd like to know by what mechanism that can happen. And if I can tell what program launched it there 'cos I wouldn't have managed to run a  file of tmp extension, as executable, manually!

[image]

Comment: This is quite common during installations. I copied `notepad.exe` to `notepad.tmp` and found that I could run it from `cmd` with the `start` command, or simply by typing its name: it even finds it in a directory in the `PATH` list. So far I have found that only `explorer` fails to run it.

Comment: @AFH heh, you're right, even `start notepad.a` works.  You can make that an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: Have you tried useing resmon -> CPU -> Associated handles to see if another process has it open (has executed it)?

Comment: File extensions don't really mean anything, except when applications expect a specific extension, so there is no requirement that an executable have any extension at all, as long as the shell knows what to do with the file. As @AFH showed, as long as the shell can be informed that "yes this really is an executable, try it" via the `start` verb,  the file's internal format is generally self-descriptive enough that it can tell the shell anything additional it needs to know about how to launch it.

Comment: @DavidPostill  anything I should be looking for there? http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FZMG48Lb

Comment: @barlop I don't see anything obvious. From the Process Explorer properties screenshot in your question it looks like the parent process has already terminated anyway. So it looks like its to late to tell what launched it. Probably an auto update of one of your still running processes, eg firewall, antivirus or whatever.

Comment: Anything else interesting in the Temp directory? Log files? Other files?

Comment: i'd note that PATHEXT is for files with no extension, though this is of a file with a foreign extension. So `PATHEXT=.EXE` is not superfluous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is quite common during installations.

I copied `notepad.exe` to `notepad.tmp` and found that I could run it from `cmd` with the `start` command, or simply by typing its name: it even finds it in a directory in the PATH list.

So far I have found that only `explorer` fails to run it.

Another non-standard executable extension is `.scr`, used for screen-savers.

Comment: though you're missing an explanation as to what method it's using.. and if there are other extensions that are autodetected

Comment: @barlop - You're right: I was quite busy when I wrote the answer, so I didn't expand it, though Karan's answer below has done a good job of explaining the checks. I also didn't explain that there is no "magic number" for batch files, so, unlike binaries, you can't copy them to arbitrary extensions.

Comment: well, that still doesn't answer the question I just asked you, of what other files with "magic numbers" are recognized e.g. maybe COM files are recognized(though obviously it'd say something along the lines of a 16bit error even if it was), and I don't have any to test that.

Comment: @barlop - Being used to Linux, where magic numbers (and the executable bit) control how files are opened, I haven't explored whether they override all non-standard Windows extensions. I do recall needing to rename Firefox `.xpi` add-ons to `.zip` in order to open with my ZIP handler, though magic numbers do influence the `explorer` context menu. I've also not tried renaming a `.exe` file to `.cmd` to see how Windows handles it. So without a lot of investigation I cannot give a definitive answer. If you find one, I'll be very interested to read it, either as a link in a comment or a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Explorer doesn't allow files with random extensions to be executed (most likely for security purposes), but for some reason *cmd* doesn't have this restriction (wonder why?) and will treat any file with the [*magic number*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) [**MZ** in ASCII (**4D 5A** in hex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_MZ_executable) as an executable.

You can test this easily with the following commands:

```
echo MZ > abc.xyz
abc.xyz
```

Of course Windows will immediately complain that the "application" is invalid, but the point is proved.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Note: The VBScript [Exec()](http://ss64.com/vb/exec.html) method behaves the same way *cmd* does.

Comment: does it only - autoexecute  **exe** type files with foreign extensions ? i.e. would it do it for any other types when the file has a foreign extension?